# JS - dates of month, by week grouping.

Tags: javascript, loops, calendar, iteration

I'm trying to document.write the week number and then the days that fall in that week. e.g  if you enter April 2016 as your desired month it would show  weekNum 
 then in week 1 the 1st is a friday, 2nd is saturday. Then week 2 the 3rd is sunday, the 4th is monday and so on for the entire month.

```
//variables
var reqMon;
var todaysDate = new Date();
var currYr = todaysDate.getFullYear();
var currMon = todaysDate.getMonth();
var currDate = todaysDate.getDate();
var currDay = todaysDate.getDay();

//creates a month array.
var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
//creates a day array.
var weekDaysArray = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
//creates an array for how many days in each month. 
var maxMonthlyDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31");

//prompts user for numeric month.
var reqMon = parseInt(prompt("Enter desired month (Jan = 1, Dec = 12)"));

//validates users month input.
while (reqMon == "" || reqMon < 1 || reqMon > 12) { 
    reqMon = prompt("Invalid Entry. Please enter the month number again.")
}

//Step 3B. 
document.write(reqMon + "/" + currDate + "/" + currYr + "<br /><br />");

//Step 4.
document.write(monthArray[reqMon -1] + " " + currYr + "<br /><br />");

var dateComb = (reqMon + "/1/" + currYr);
var userIdate = new Date(dateComb);
var userDay = new Date(dateComb).getDay();
var userDate = new Date(dateComb).getDate();
var maxDays = maxMonthlyDays[reqMon -1];
var numberWeeks = maxMonthlyDays[reqMon - 1] / 6;

// ****************  STEP 5 **************.
//loops through weeks of month.
for (x = 1; x <= maxMonthlyDays[reqMon] / 6; x++) {
    document.write("<b>Week " + x + "<br /></b>");

    while (userDay <= 6 && userDate <= maxMonthlyDays[reqMon]) { 
        document.write(weekDaysArray[userDay] + " " + userDate + "<br />");
        userDay++;
        userDate++;
    }
}
```

I can get the weekNum iterated and outputted to screen, I can get the total number of days in the desired month to iterate and output. But I can't seem to get "only the days 1,2,3, etcc  to output under the proper weekNum.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I am not sure what exactly you need though.

```
    for (x = 1; x <= numberWeeks; x++) {
        document.write("<b>Week " + x + "<br /></b>");
        while (userDay <= 6 && userDate <= maxDays) {
            document.write(weekDaysArray[userDay] + " " + userDate + "<br />");
            userDay++;
            userDate++;
        }
        userDay = 0;
    }
```